# Mysql Group By Query Performance Very Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, group-by, innodb

I am using Mysql 5.7 
I have table which having 1 900 516 rows.
My query performing group by on column which is already indexed but still takes time for execution. Below is my query,execution plan and table schema.

```
    select  `type`,count(`type`)
    from templog 
    group by `type` ;
```

Query Explain format

```
            {
          "query_block": {
            "select_id": 1,
            "cost_info": {
              "query_cost": "376984.80"
            },
            "grouping_operation": {
              "using_filesort": false,
              "table": {
                "table_name": "templog",
                "access_type": "index",
                "possible_keys": [
                  "templog_type_idx"
                ],
                "key": "templog_type_idx",
                "used_key_parts": [
                  "type"
                ],
                "key_length": "1",
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 1856244,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 1856244,
                "filtered": "100.00",
                "using_index": true,
                "cost_info": {
                  "read_cost": "5736.00",
                  "eval_cost": "371248.80",
                  "prefix_cost": "376984.80",
                  "data_read_per_join": "84M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                  "templogid",
                  "type"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Table Schema

```
    CREATE TABLE `templog` (
          `templogid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `userid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
          `type` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
          `location` json DEFAULT NULL,
          `ip` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
          `createdat` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
          PRIMARY KEY (`templogid`),
          KEY `templog_type_idx` (`type`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1900516 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How to optimize this query?

Comment: How long does that take? Is type really indexed? it's not visible in your schema.

Comment: The execution plan looks fine to me (the only minor microoptimization would be to use int instead of bigint for the primary key, if that is an option with your data). Could you clarify "slow", since slow is relative?

Answer (score 1):

It must read all the 1.9M rows in the `type` index.  This takes *some* time.  The `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` confirms that it is doing the best it can with the schema and query as given.

If this is a "log" that is never `UPDATEd` or `DELETEd` after writing, then it may be possible to use Data Warehouse tricks.

By building and incrementally maintaining a Summary Table, you could speed up the equivalent query by perhaps 10-fold.  More [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Comment: thank you.The link that is provided by you is really very interesting.